# Is there any way to show camera stream and draw something on top of it (in linux)?

Tags: linux, opengl-es, arm, gstreamer

I am using freescale gpu sdk,Open GLES APIs for drawing and Gstreamer APIs for camera streaming for ARM architecture. It is possible in my case to do them separately but i want to know is there any way to show camera stream and draw something on it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of freescale's processor (such as imx6) have multiple framebuffer overlay (/dev/fb0, /dev/fb1, /dev/fb2, ...).
You can then stream camera content on fb1, and draw on fb0, for exemple.
knowing that all those frambuffer are not activated by default.

Comment: Thanks John madieu. i have two device nodes, /dev/fb0 and /dev/fb1 when i checked. I am using an image with X11 support.As far as i know X11 internally uses /dev/fb0. correct me if i am wrong. will the thing i want work with this image?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I don't really know the behavior of X11. That's why I suggest you to disable X11 and make direct rendering with openGL via openGL DRI (Direct Rendering infrastructure) driver and DRM (Direct  Rendering Manager) on one of the two framebuffers, and stream your camera on the other fb. (May be I am wrong and I hope someone else will correct me if it is the case)

[This is a french documentation on how DRM and DRI works.](http://sysmic.org/pub/Pile%20graphique%20Linux/Sysmic%20-%20J.%20Pouiller%20-%20Pile%20graphique%20Linux.pdf)

I have already faced this problem in the past.
I had to stream video with GStreamer and draw text over with pango. First thing I did was to generate a minimal image (with GStreamer enabled of course) but without any X11 library. For me (maybe it's different on your module), GStreamer used the /dev/fb1 node by default, and I then used /dev/fb0 for pango rendering.

It was quite easy to do that after several tests. So I also suggest you to make tests, try different things, different way, and I hope it will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks John. Can you please help me in directing video to /dev/fb1 i.e. how   will i set /dev/fb1 for camera streaming and /dev/fb0 for graphics rendering? I am totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your concrete root file system but if you are using the one generated with Freescale Yocto for i.MX6 the default configuration is at /usr/share/vssconfig

In that file you can specify which framebuffer gstreamer uses. By default /dev/fb0 is the BACKGROUND framebuffer and /dev/fb1 is the FOREGROUND framebuffer.

You can make gstreamer to draw in /dev/fb0 while you draw using cairo over /dev/fb1 (mmap /dev/fb1 and cairo_image_surface_create_for_data) controlling the transperency level with ioctls() over /dev/fb1.